# For every invertible operator on a Hilbert space, there is a neighbourhood of the operator for which operators in that neighbourhood are invertible.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $A \in B(H)$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space, and $B(H)$ denotes the collection of all bounded linear operators $A : H \rightarrow H$ on $H$, with the usual operator norm. Suppose furthermore that $A$ is invertible, i.e. there is $A^{-1} \in B(H)$ such that $A A^{-1} = id_H = A^{-1} A$.

I want to show that there is a neighbourhood of $A$ for which all operators in that neighbourhood are also invertible, i.e., there exists $\varepsilon > 0 $ such that for all $B \in B(H)$ with $ \| A - B \| < \varepsilon$, $B$ is invertible.

Not sure how to begin this argument. Have been told to consider using power series. A reference from a book would be appreciated as I am pretty certain this is a standard result. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: It is sufficient to prove this for the identity operator $I$. (why?) More precisely, you can show that if $||A||<1$ then $I-A$ is invertible. Indeed, show that the geometric series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} A^n$ converges, and its limit is an inverse of $I-A$.